# Can only get one list item to show at one time despite the list items array containing more values

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-formbuilder, nativescript-angular

I have a problem where only one list item show up at one time, despite there being more than one item in the iterated list. I'm not sure whether this is down to a layout problem or something else.

When I dump `myForm.get('questions').controls` I can see that there are multiple controls in there the more I click on the `addQuestion` button.

What could be wrong?

This is my form:

```
public myForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  questions: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

Which is passed to the list view:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
  <ListView [items]="myForm.get('questions').controls">
    <ng-template let-question="item">
      <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <question [question]="question"></question>
      </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <Button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" text="textfield" (tap)="addQuestion('textfield')"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

When you click the add question button this is run, which adds a new item to the list:

```
 getQuestion(type: string): FormGroup {

    return this.fb.group({
      type: type,
      label: null,
      question: '',
      answer: null
    });
  }

  addQuestion(type: string): void {
    this.questions.push(this.getQuestion(type));

    // Dumped the value rather than the controls to make it clearer what the array contains
    console.dump(this.questions.value) 
  }
```

`<question>` component template:

```
<StackLayout class="question-item" [formGroup]="question">
    <TextField class="label input" formControlName="question" hint="Question"></TextField>
    <TextField class="input" formControlName="answer" hint="Answer"></TextField>
  </StackLayout>
```

Here's a screenshot of the dump after a few clicks on the button:

[image: dump]

But as you can see here only one item is showing (I've hide some of the buttons from the pasted template here so it's more readable):

[image: list]

**EDIT:** I just tried with a normal array, containing some objects. And even with that only the first one shows up.

Comment: Before your edit I would say this may be related to the `OnPush` strategy because `FormArray.push()` mutate controls and do not create new references. Now I'm wondering if your problem is not your `ListView` component.

Comment: What is `this.questions`? What's it referring to and how have you done it?

Comment: @AJT_82 This is resolved, I was using a ScrollView on the top level component which caused this to break.. Took me forever to find it.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You should explain the solution and how did you find it... I am having a similar issue...